# Copy records in the same table

Tags: sql

I've got column Cars with column "Owner".

I has one owner , and he has 10 cars.

Now I've 2 additional person who has the same cars, so I need Add 20 records to my table.

Wiht only one column different:

Something like:

```
Insert into Cars (NameOfCar,NameOfOwner) 
Select NameOfCar,'"Robert Kubica' Where NameOfOwner='Schumacher'. 

Insert into Cars (NameOfCar,NameOfOwner) 
Select NameOfCar,'"Hakashi Honda' Where NameOfOwner='Schumacher'.
```

Comment: Your SQL should work - what is your question?

Comment: So, what is the problem with the above 2 statements?

Comment: I suspect there is actually a question in there somewhere and I think it'll be answer with something like "Insert into Cars (NameOfCar,NameOfOwner) Select c.NameOfCar,'Robert Kubica' From Cars AS c Where c.NameOfOwner='Schumacher'" although perhaps not exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that you are missing **FROM** clause in your queries, please try adding it.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `From` clause:

```
Insert into cars (NameOfCar,NameOfOwner)
Select NameOfCar, 'Hakashi Honda'
From cars
Where NameOfOwner='Schumacher'
```